# Python Django 4.0.3 static css files aren't being served

Tags: django

My static CSS files aren't being served but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Here is my base.html file in my template:
`settings.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-mejzq0og40v2luq46-1uy0b^s$a8_mk9p@$(d)z&w3vjd(bsb0'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Inside the static directory I run tree and I get this:

```
static
└── css
        └── blog.css
```

This is `templates/blog/base.html`:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
                <link href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="content">
                        {% block content %}
                        {% endblock %}
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                        <h2>My blog</h2>
                        <p>This is my blog.</p>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I look at various different other stackoverflow answers and django-forum answers regarding the imports and everything seems to be right, but it's still not working.

EDIT:
I tried moving the css directory into a new blog directory like this:

```
static
└── blog
    └── css
        └── blog.css
```

Since that didn't work, I tried changing the static link in `base.html` to be like this: `<link href="{% static 'blog/css/blog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`, which also gave me a 404 error.

Comment: Did you try adding `STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))` to your settings.py?

Comment: Also try `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` instead of `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` ?

Comment: @SOuser I tried that and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best friend when having issues with static files is
`python manage.py findstatic -v2 "relative/path/style.css"`
It shows what paths it searches in and if it finds the file. Relative path is same you refer it in e.g. `{% static %}` tag.

If you see it doesn't search where you expect it to (your case)

1. Check if app with `static/<this file>` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. If it's not in such dir, check if dir path is added to `STATICFILES_DIRS` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs

Otherwise confirm how you refer the file correctly. It's done with path relative to any of configured static dirs (default `<project>/<app>/static` for each app in `INSTALLED_APPS` and ones in `STATICFILES_DIRS`) and doesn't include "static/" part itself.

So if you have file as

> "my_project/my_app/static/**styles/custom.css**"

it's referred by highlighted part.

Or if you use app namespacing for static files:

> "my_project/my_app/static/**my_app/another_style.css**"

*NOTE*: django will serve files ONLY when using `runserver` and `DEBUG=True` - it's not meant and won't work in deployment, you need separate configuration for it.